# the regular expressions in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a question about regular expressions in tcl
what does the following code means:

```
set servRef "servRef=(\\d+)"
```

set the variable servRef as "servRef=(\d+)"; what does this mean?

the code following above one is to pass the servRef as a patarmer to a function, take the servRef value and send the message to it. so what does the "servRef=(\d+)" means )

Comment: this line is just a plain ol' variable assignment.  It's got nothing to do with regular expressions.  is `$servRef` later used in some way?

Comment: Yep, it will set the variable named "servRef" to the literal string `servRef=(\d+)` (one backslash is removed as it escapes the following backslash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've overthinking the problem a little. What you have

```
set servRef "servRef=(\\d+)"
```

is just a command that sets the variable `servRef` to the value `servRef=(\d+)`
. That value may be used by another command as a regular expression later, but it's just a value here.

Its useful to remember that Tcl doesn't have many context sensitive constructs.

Comment: Many? One of Tcl's strongest features is that it has none; everything is parsed in exactly the same way. (Except for the commands that reparse selected arguments, but they're documented to do just that). Occasionally it's a little frustrating for newcomers as they try to use shortcuts from other languages — won't work with Tcl which is too stupid to be outwitted — but the regularity means that extending is simple and easy to comprehend.

Comment: @Donal - I consider the {*} construct to be somewhat context sensitive. One might also think the same of $ for variable substitution. Admittedly, it's pushing the definition of "context sensitive" a little, but I didn't want to go into any detail in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show enough of the context to be sure, but I would guess that later on $serfRef will be used as the pattern to match in a regexp command which scans some input for a string like `serfRef=1234` and extracts the 1234 into a sub-match variable for later use.  For more info see the [Tcl wiki regexp page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/regexp).